# How can I access a URL's named group in a Django Generic View?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

Given a url like: `url(r'^foos/(?P<foo_id>[0-9]+)/bars/new/$'`

How can I access `foo_id` from within a `CreateView` instance in order to populate a foreign key form field? I've tried a number of approaches (most recently overriding `get_context_data` and trying to pull the value out of the request object or from kwargs) without success.

There may be a better way to do this (e.g. formsets), but I'd like to make as few changes as possible to my existing flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override get_form_kwargs or get_initial depending on how you are going to pass the instance to the form:

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['foo'] = Foo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['foo_id'])
        return kwargs
```

Or

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    def get_initial(self):
        """Return the initial data to use for forms on this view."""
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['foo'] = Foo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['foo_id'])
        return initial
```

Comment: `get_initial` seems to do the trick. Though, I'd be curious to know what you're getting at by saying, "depending on how you are going to pass the instance to the form".

Comment: If you have a custom initialization method in your form like this ```def __init__(self, foo, *args, **kwargs)``` then you would need to use the first example.